# Parellel Processing Spring Batch StaxEventItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job defined as follows.

```
<batch:step id="convert">
    <batch:tasklet >
        <batch:chunk reader="contentItemReader" writer="contentItemWriter"
                             processor="processor" commit-interval="10000" >
        </batch:chunk>
     </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

The contentItemReader is as follows.

```
 @Bean
 public StaxEventItemReader contentItemReader() {
        StaxEventItemReader reader = new StaxEventItemReader();
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("ContentItem");
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(baseDirectory.concat(inputFile)));
        reader.setUnmarshaller(contentItemUnmarshaller());
        return reader;
 }
```

Everything works great except that its a bit slower then I would like.     I know that this reader is not thread safe.  So I don't think I can add a taskExecutor to the tasklet.  ContentItems are not dependent on each other so I want to feed data into the processors in parallel.  The ItemProcessing may be fairly time consuming.  So although I know I can't have a multithreaded reader,  I should be able to have a multithreaded item processing.

The ItemWriters will also need to be single threaded since I am using a flatFile ItemWriter.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your reader in something like this:

```
public class SynchronizedWrapperReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T> {

  private ItemReader<T> itemReader;
  private boolean isStream = false;

  public void setItemReader(ItemReader<T> itemReader) {
    this.itemReader = itemReader;
    if (itemReader instanceof ItemStream) {
      isStream = true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (isStream) {
      ((ItemStream) itemReader).close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    if (isStream) {
      ((ItemStream) itemReader).open(new ExecutionContext());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized T read() throws Exception {
    return itemReader.read();
  }
}
```

And the same for your writer.

Please note, that the order is no longer guaranteed.

### Edited:

There was a comment on how to use it in a config.xml. So, here is a simple example how to use the Wrapper with a FlatFileItemReader:

```
<batch:step id="convert">
    <batch:tasklet >
        <batch:chunk reader="wrappedReader" writer="..."
                             processor="..." commit-interval="10000" >
        </batch:chunk>
     </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="wrappedReader" class=[package].SynchronizedWrapperReader">
   <property name="itemReader">
      <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
          <property .../>
          <property .../>
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I assume you intended to couple this with a taskExecutor on the step configuration.  I can give this a try.  I also used a solution using a taskExecutor within a custom itemWriter while moving all my item processing logic there.  This seems to work although I am not getting the speed up I expected which may have more to do with disk I/O being the limiting factor.

Comment: yes, you are right. you have to use an AsyncTaskExecutor and you have to set the throttle limit.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this out.  While functionally it seems to be a correct answer,  just as I was seeing with an Async SI job, the speed up isn't really that great. Probably due to disk I/O being the limited factor.

Comment: How do we use this in my `context` XML configuration?

Comment: @user1629109 I added an example to my answer above

Comment: Thank you @HansjoergWingeier : I'm using `StaxEventItemReader` instead of `FlatFileItemReader`. Do you know if that configuration would work for `StaxEventItemReader`? My reader looks like this http://pastebin.com/LnzGtBS7

Comment: That doesn't mapper, the wrapper just makes sure, that multiple threads are synchronized when they call the "real" reader.

Answer (score 0):

Since version `3.0.4` Spring Batch offers a wrapper class (like Hansjoerg Wingeier) out of the box: [`SynchronizedItemStreamReader<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html)