# Spring Batch Processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement in Spring Batch where I have a file with thousands of records coming in a sorted order.The key field is product code.
The file may have multiple records of the same product code.The requirement is that I have to group the records that have the same
product Code in a collection (i.e List) and then send them over to a method i.e validateProductCodes(List prodCodeList).
I am looking for the best way to do this.The approach I thought of was to read every record in the Processor and then build a collection 
of records for the same product code in the processor.If at any point in the processor,if the product code in the record is different than it would imply that
the productCode grouping is complete and the validateProductCodes() can be called for that group of records with the same product code.Also I am using a Step.So does 
not that automatically mean that the process is multithreaded?Meaning Groups of records with same productCode will be processed in a multithreaded way.Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832341/custom-itemreader-to-return-more-than-one-rowsbased-on-some-column-value-to-it

Comment: Thanks @LucaBassoRicci.Will try and understand the solution.

Comment: I went through the example.But I am unsure as to how to implement it.In your example,you have used  private BreakKeyStrategy<Object> strategy;This looks like a class I think that needs to take care of the group change based on the key.But I am unsure as to how to write this class.Is there a parent interface or class to extend or implement.Don't see much documentation about this.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions in your question: first, you want to know how to group the items together and second how they are processed.

In order to group them, you could create a group reader as Luca suggested or something like:

```
public class GroupReader<I> implements ItemReader<List<I>>{
  private SingleItemPeekableItemReader<I> reader;
  private ItemReader<I> peekReaderDelegate;

  public void setReader(ItemReader<I> reader) {
      peekReaderDelegate = reader;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(peekReaderDelegate, "The 'itemReader' may not be null");
    this.reader= new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<I>();
    this.reader.setDelegate(delegateReader);
  }

  @Override
  public List<I> read() throws Exception {
    State state = State.NEW;
    List<I> group = null;
    I item = null;

    while (state != State.COMPLETE) {
      item = reader.read();

      switch (state) {
        case NEW: {
          if (item == null) {
            // end reached
            state = State.COMPLETE;
            break;
          }

          group = new ArrayList<I>();
          group.add(item);
          state = State.READING;
          I nextItem = reader.peek();
          if (isItAKeyChange(item, nextItem)) {
            state = State.COMPLETE;
          }
          break;
        }
        case READING: {
          group.add(item);

          // peek and check if there the peeked entry has a new date
          I nextItem = peekEntry();
          if (isItAKeyChange(item, nextItem)) {
            state = State.COMPLETE;
          }
          break;
        }
        default: {
          throw new org.springframework.expression.ParseException(groupCounter, "ParsingError: Reader is in an invalid state");
        }
      }
    }

    return group;
  }
}
```

For every key, this reader will return a list with all elements matching this key. Therefore, the grouping ist done directly in the reader. 
You cannot do that with a processor, as you described.

Your second question about multithreading.
Now, using a step does not necessarily mean, that the step is processed with several threads.

In order to do that, you need set an AsyncTaskExecutor and you have to set the throttle limit.

But if you do that, your reader must be threadsafe, or otherwise your grouping won't work. You could do that by simply defining the read method above as synchronized.

Another way could be to write a small SynchronizedWrapperReader, as suggested in this question: [Parellel Processing Spring Batch StaxEventItemReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898869/parellel-processing-spring-batch-staxeventitemreader)

Please note, depending on your target you are writing to, you probably also have to synchronize the writer, and if necessary to reorder the result.

Comment: Thanks @Hansjoerg.I will look at the solutions provided and try and solve my problem.

Comment: I went through the code snippet above.At a high level I do understand the code but I still have some questions-basic maybe.First is what does getGroupBreakStrategy do.Is this a Strategy class that I need to write.Not clear about that.Second,STATE.Not sure which class to extend or interface to implement.Third,where do I specify the key on the basis of which the grouping or the change needs to occur.Thanks

Comment: Sry, I missed that. I fixed the code above. I replaced it with a call to isItAkeyChange(). You have to implement this method yourself. In there has to be the rule, which indicates, that a new group starts. Note that your isItAKeyChange() method must be able to handle a nextitem==null and returning true.

Comment: Thanks @Hansjoerg.Which package does the STATE class belong to?

Comment: There is one class in the API org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.State.But that does not have any of the variables - COMPLETE,NEW etc.

Comment: You have to define your own :-). Just make an Enum with the used states. You can define it directly in the reader.

Comment: Thanks Hansjoerg for your help.

Comment: @Hansjoerg Wingeier hi, this a pretty interesting piece of code ! We have the same kind of need and handled it differently (and somehow poorly). So I would to know: if the original reader (which will be the `peekReaderDelegate`) is a `SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean` that has a pageSize of 10000 for example. Like OP, items need to be "agregated" from multiple continuous line (because of join queries). Would that solution work if items to agregate into one, are on line 9998, 9999, 10000 and 10001 or would it be cut in two agregating objects (if you see what I mean) ?

Comment: @Asoub I don't see a reason, why it shouldn't work. Of course, you need to have the result set ordered. Moreover, since a Paging-Reader will launch several selects at different timepoints, you have to ensure that the query will always select the same entries.

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier Could you please post complete configuration (xml config) for this.