# Passing data from itemreader to processor

Tags: spring-batch

How is the data read is passed from reader to Itemprocessor in Spring batch? Is there a queue where it is put from ItemReader's read method which is consumed by ItemProcessor? I have to read 10 records at a time from a database and process 5 at a time in the ItemProcessor's process method. ItemProcessor is taking the records one by one and I want to change it to 5 records at a time in the process method.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not easy for the reader of your question to understand what you are asking. Could you please rephrase it according to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item that is returned from the read method of a reader will be forwarded to the processor as one item.

If you want to collect a group of items and pass them as a group to the processor, you need a reader that groups them.

You could implement something like a group-wrapper.
I explained such an approach in another answer: [Spring Batch Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930775/spring-batch-processor/31943265#31943265)